# How to select and delete a specific region in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, drawing

I am having an issue selecting the region between the black lines. The grill area has two colors (gray & black). I want to remove the gray area between the black lines without removing or selecting other areas in my image.

Thanks in advance[image]
[image]

Comment: What grill area? What grey area? I can't tell what the image is supposed to be, and I don't see any grey area between black lines, either. I see an area in the middle that is black with a grey pattern. Is that what you're talking about? And why are there two identical pictures? The way the question is currently asked, it's very unclear.

Comment: If you figured it out why not leave it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure this image is on a separate layer with a white background so you can see the result, then:

1. Double-click on the layer icon to bring up the Layer Style dialog window
2. Move the triangular slides as shown on "This layer"
3. To split the two halves, hold the Alt key as you drag one half
4. You will see only the black lines

See below the Layer style and the resulting selected image against the white background. It is still a separate layer.

If you want to select the remaining parts of the image simply switch to the Channels and Ctrl-Click on the RGB channel, it will select what you see. Alternately, you can add a blank layer above the image layer, select both the blank and the image layers, then press Ctrl-E to merge them together. You will have just the black areas remaining.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to select **color range option**, from
Choose Select > Color Range.

> The Color Range command selects a specified color or color range
>   within an existing selection or an entire image.

[image: photoshop color range]

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: Use the magic wand to select the area (and modify the options as needed prior to doing this, but don't get too uptight about the details, just get it close).

Then, use modify selection options to select your area in the best way possible.

Option #2: Use the pen tool to select the area which you want to modify (close the path). Save the path. Change the path to a selection (channels palette) and then make your modifications.  - also can use the modify selections after the selection has been made as this selection is likely to be a hard edge

Option #3: use a paintbush in the QuickMask mode and specifically select the area you want to use (jump in and out of quickmask mode easily with the buttons at the bottom of the toolbox), but be sure to save the selection before letting it go... or losing it in your history.